# Pass html.dropdownlistfor current value to Actionlink?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

is it possible to pass `@Html.DropDownListFor` current value to action link? I want to pass the template value to the `Sample` controller with `Create` Action. Below code not work because `@Model.SurveyTemplate` does not return any value. Is it need `JavaScript` to retrieve? Please guide me.

Drop Down List:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Survey_Template, "Survey Template")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Survey_Template, new SelectList(
                  new List<Object>{
                       new { value = "Style1" , text = "Style1"  },
                       new { value = "Style2" , text = "Style2" },
                       new { value = "Style3" , text = "Style3"}
                    },
                  "value",
                  "text",
            0))
```

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("_", "Create", "Sample",
            new { template = @Model.Survey_Template },
            new { @id = "popup-link", @class = "classname2" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this with `JavaScript`, the *razor syntax* is recognized only on **server side**. This means that `@Model.Survey_Template` will be rendered when user request the page and will have the default value.

If you choose to do it with `JavaScript` remember that you need to save the base url and to append parameters to it based on what has been selected.

This steps will help you to achieve your desired result:

1. Attach a `change` event on your dropdown.
2. Get the selected `value` and construct the new url
3. Replace the url (`href`) of the action (`<a .. />`)

**Note:** I didn't write the code because I want you to surpass yourself.

---

I think what you try to achive it's a `form` with `GET`.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sample", FormMethod.GET)){
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Survey_Template, "Survey Template")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Survey_Template, new SelectList(
        new List<Object>{
           new { value = "Style1" , text = "Style1"  },
           new { value = "Style2" , text = "Style2" },
           new { value = "Style3" , text = "Style3"}
        },
        "value",
        "text",
    0))

    <input type="submit" value="_" class="classname2" id="popup-link" />
}
```